# Product topologies: $T_\text{prod} \subseteq T_\text{unif} \subseteq T_\text{box} $

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, product-space

I want to show the opposite containment of basis, i.e. $B_\text{box} \subseteq B_\text{unif} \subseteq B_\text{prod} $.

Starting with $B_\text{unif} \subseteq B_\text{prod} $, the basic open set of $B_\text{unif} = B_\epsilon(x)$ where $\epsilon$ is generated by $d(x,y) = \sup\{ d_1= \min\{1,| x-y|\}\}$ and basic open set of $B_\text{prod} = \left\{ \prod_{n \in \Bbb{N}} U_n : U_n  = \Bbb{R}\  \text{ for all but finitely many } n\right\}$, then pick a $y_n$ in $B_\epsilon(x)$, we want to show that $y_n$ is also in $\prod U_n$ we know that there exists a finite set $F$, s.t $U_n = \Bbb{R} \ \forall\  n \in \Bbb{N} \setminus F$ for $y_n$ s.t $n$ is in  $\Bbb{N} \setminus F$ then $y_n$ is obviously $n$ $U_n$, for $n$ in $F$, we know that by metrizability of $\Bbb{R}$ there exit a $C_{\epsilon_n}(y) \subseteq U_n$, so pick $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2} \min \{ \epsilon_n : n \in F \}$ which we can do since $F$ is finite then for $n$ in $F$: $d_1(x_n, y_n) \leq \sup(d_1(x_k, y_k))$ for $k$ in $\Bbb{N}  = d \leq \epsilon \leq \epsilon_n$ and hence $B_\epsilon(x) \subseteq \prod U_n$ as required. 
For containment between $B_\text{box} \subseteq B_\text{unif}$ $B_\text{box} = \prod U_n$: s.t $U_n $is open in $\Bbb{R}$. so pick each $U_n = B_{\epsilon_n}$ where $\epsilon_n$ is generated by $d_1$ which we can do by metrizability of $\Bbb{R}$,  then $\prod U_n \subseteq B_\epsilon(x)$ since $d_1 \leq d = \sup(d_1)$

I also want to show strict containment so for instance $ (0,1) \times (3,5) \times (1,2)\times\cdots$ is a set of $T_\text{box}$ but not $T _\text{unif}$ and $(2,0) \times (2,0)\times\cdots$ is an open set of $T_\text{unif}$ but not $T_\text{prod}$.

I'm not sure if I can pick $\epsilon$ since shouldn't it just be supremum of all the $\epsilon_n$ generated by $d_1$ I'm sorry my thoughts with this proof are all over the place, if someone can help me understand it better I would really appreciate it.

Comment: If $B_1, B_2$ are bases for topologies $T_1,T_2$ on the same set , and $B_1\subset B_2$ then $T_1\subset T_2.$  So you cannot show the opposite containments in  your Q .

Comment: @user254665 but for instance let $B_1$ = all singletons in $\Bbb{R}$ and let $B_2$ be the set of all open intervals in $\Bbb{R}$, $B_1$ generates the discete topology, $B_2$ generates the usual topology, but $B_1 \subset B_2$ and $T_2 \subset T_1$

Comment: $B_1\subset B_2$ means that every member of $B_1$ is a member of $B_2$.......$B_1$ is not  a subset of $B_2,$  Singleton subsets of $R$ are not members of $B_2.$ Every member of $B_1$ is a subset of a member of $B_2 . $ What you are doing is finding bases $B_1. B_2, B_3$ such that every memer of $B_j$ is a subset of a member of $B_{j+1}$.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).